# Error 500 at recaptcha when login magento 2

Tags: magento2

I work with magento 2, I added recaptha to logging in, but I have a 500 error. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: Can you share the error with us?

Answer (score 0):

500 internal server error means that you must have the error logged in the **server log files**.

You can also check in Magento logs in ***/var/log/system.log*** and ***/var/log/exception.log***

A 500 internal server error in this case can be caused by file permissions on ***/pub/media/captcha/admin.***

For best security practices, the owner of the Magento filesystem should be one user, and the user that PHP or the webserver runs as a different user.